# Publishing updated extension to marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created a vscode color theme extension. I also published it in the marketplace. I then made some changes to the extension but now I'm not able to publish the updated extension since I forgot the Personal Access Token. 
Is there any way to overcome this scenario?

Comment: Just create a new personal access token for the account the extension was published with.

Comment: would it effect any already installed stats such as number of installs or downloads in the marketplace?

Comment: no. Recreating the PAT does not effect any stats. However recreating a publisher or editing the extension id will effect those properties.

Comment: I'm in the same position now, cant access the account, any solutions